# BigInt multiplication and to_string implementation outputs too many zeros

Tags: c++, c++11

I created the following for multiplying two big integers stored with base `1,000,000,000` as a `vector<int32_t>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
constexpr T power_of_10(T n)
{
    return n < 0 ? 0 : n == 0 ? 1 : (n == 1 ? 10 : 10 * power_of_10(n - 1));
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T base_value = power_of_10<T>(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10);

template<typename T>
constexpr T max_value = base_value<T> - 1;

class BigInt {
private:
    static constexpr const std::uint32_t base = base_value<std::uint32_t>;
    static constexpr const std::uint32_t max_digits = std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::digits10;
    std::vector<std::uint64_t> digits;
    
public:
    BigInt(const char* value) : BigInt(std::string(value))
    {
    }
    
    BigInt(const std::string& value)
    {
        constexpr const int stride = std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::digits10;
        const std::size_t size = value.size() / stride;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            auto it = value.begin();
            auto jt = value.begin();
            std::advance(it, i * stride);
            std::advance(jt, (i * stride) + stride);
            digits.push_back(std::stoull(std::string(it, jt)));
        }
        
        if (value.size() % stride)
        {
            auto remainder = std::string(value.begin() + size * stride, value.end());
            digits.push_back(std::stoull(remainder));
        }
        
        
        std::reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end());
    }

    BigInt& multiply(const BigInt& other)
    {
        std::vector<std::uint64_t> product = std::vector<std::uint64_t>(digits.size() + other.digits.size(), 0);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < other.digits.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::uint64_t carry = 0, total = 0;
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < digits.size(); ++j)
            {
                total = product.at(i + j) + (other.digits[i] * digits[j]) + carry;
                carry = total / base;
                total %= base;

                product.at(i + j) = total;
            }

            if (carry)
            {
                product[i + digits.size()] = carry;
            }
        }
        
        digits = product;
        return *this;
    }
    
    std::string to_string() {
        std::string result = std::to_string(digits[digits.size() - 1]);
//
//        for (std::int64_t i = digits.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
//        {
//            std::string group = std::to_string(digits[i]);
//            while (group.size() < max_digits) {
//                group = '0' + group;
//            }
//            result += group;
//        }
        
        for (std::int64_t i = digits.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            std::uint64_t value = digits[i];
            std::uint32_t divisor = base;

            while(divisor)
            {
                if (divisor != base)
                {
                    result += (value / divisor) + '0';
                }
                value %= divisor;
                divisor /= 10;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    BigInt a = "5000000000";
    BigInt b = "5000000000";
    
    std::cout<<a.multiply(b).to_string()<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"25000000000000000000"<<"\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I print the result of the multiplication, I am getting `5,000,000,000 * 5,000,000,000` = `250,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000` which has way too many zeroes!

It should have 18 zeroes, but mine has 34.

I believe my multiplication algorithm is correct and my `to_string` is incorrect because `500 * 500` prints correctly as `25,000`.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Have you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: And if you one of those folks who think debuggers are for the weak, where are the print statements showing the correct numbers are being computed at each step? Does `0 0 0 250000000` look like the correct contents of `digits` at the end of `multiply`?

Comment: There's something weird happening when you go from using `500,000,000` to `5,000,000,000`. You get 4 digits instead of 2, and 2 more iterations of the for loop in your `to_string` method, and that final very long number: https://godbolt.org/z/6nPa3rEYo (8 zeroes), https://godbolt.org/z/oEG6vPvWq (9 zeroes)

Comment: @rturrado; It is because `digits.size() = 2` for both numbers. I add them together to get the length of the `product` vector. I updated the code to fix it and added comments. Still no luck figuring out why it prints more or less digits.

Comment: *I updated the code to fix it and added comments.* -- You should update code *after* you've debugged it and get a handle on what's wrong.  Just randomly trying stuff will almost never work.

Comment: You also have an issue if both of those numbers are `500000`.  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e465b8ca9ad32f00)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I fixed the multiplication and I know it's 100% correct if I use `base10`. So if I set `base = 10` and `max_digits = 1`, it will work for any number. But for `base 1,000,000,000` it will not work. It's because of my constructor where I am not properly converting from `base 10` to `base 1b`. I will have to write `%` and `/` operator to convert properly from string input to `base 1b`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line:

```
product[digits.size() + 1] = static_cast<T>(carry);
```

The index `digits.size() + 1` is incorrect. It should be `digits.size() + j`.